# check the current activity in if condition

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am working on an android application so I need to check if the user is at some activity say "xyz" then proceed or change background colour etc. How can I check the current activity in if condition like

```
if (xyz activity){
    set Background Color 
    // Do something
}
```

How can I do this in runtime so that whenever user goes to any screen this condition becomes true and then the below code works?

Comment: actually i need it on socket connect and disconnect events so that whenever it connects or disconnects the colour of the activity changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(getActivity() instanceof TheWantedActivity){
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i follow your question than put your background code in your `OnResume();` if the activity is in foreground its `onResume` always called.

Comment: i have a global class where all my methods and events are made which is extending the application so i need to check the activity in socket onconnect and onDisconnect events.

Answer (score 0):

In each activity or "screen" a user can see or interact with, a class is designated to that view.  So if you want to set the background to activity xyz, you do not need to check if the user is there.  You need to just load the background you specify within the onCreate(Bundle bundle) method with "setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout)".   This layout should be stored in your res/layout folder after you create an activity.  So for example, if your activity is named StartActivity.java, the layout file saved in res/layout will most likely be named activity_start.xml.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer Saurabh provided isn't promising enough you can take 
[ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) in your Application class, It will only work API 14 and above